# Usage of 'out of' at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

Is it possible to use 'out of' in the sense of 'from among' *at the beginning of a sentence*?

Would the examples below sound grammatical and natural with use of 'out of'in this sense?

> This story is about the Dyatlov pass mystery. A group of Russian skiers headed by Dyatlov set off on a journey to mountains where the skiers met their death. Out of ten skiers, one man fell ill and turned back, which helped him to remain alive. The others were murdered by an unknown compelling force.

and

> Rescuers delivered frozen bodies of the Dyatlov group to the morgue of a small town located 15 km south-west of the Ural Mountains. Out of the delivered corpses, a forensic scientist chose one to start the procedure of thawing.

Comment: Clearly, you just did. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: 'From' (or a re-ordering: 'A forensic scientist chose one of ...') would sound far more idiomatic (to my ear) in your second example. This is not available in your first example, as there isn't a 'pick / select' verb. 'Out of' seems to work if you then list comprehensive subsets. 'Of the ten skiers involved, one man fell ill and turned back ...' would stand alone.

Comment: _Out of the night that covers me, Black as the Pit from pole to pole_

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth From your explanation I've inferred that this phrasing is unidiomatic and is not quite correct. Am I right? You recommend 'from' for the second example and 'of the ten skiers involved' for the first one.Thanks.

Comment: @Jon Hanna I can write and say whatever I want. Of course, any phrasing is possible for me. That fact does not make my speech and texts correct for other speakers of English. I didn't use 'out of' in this sense at the beginning of a sentence before. I am curious whether such a usage is correct or justified.

Comment: But why do you think it might not be? I don't see what answer to give here beyond "yes"

Comment: @LittleEva _From among the night that covers me_ makes no sense. The OP is correct that the quote doesn't really reflect the same sense of the phrase.

Comment: @Barmar—Well, I would go so far as to say that it doesn’t make poetic sense. Which is why, I suppose, William Ernest Henley chose to open Invictus in the manner he did. However, to say that it is not possible or permissible to use *'out of' in the sense of 'from among' at the beginning of a sentence?* is incorrect, as Mr. Lawler clearly demonstrated. *Out of and from among* are, in fact, acceptable equivalents for the usage OP described. I, personally, wouldn’t be so quick to dismiss Mr. Lawler’s judgment, at least when it comes to the English language. For detail & references, see my answer.

Comment: @LittleEva I never said it's not possible to use it at the beginning of a sentence. Just that the example that Lawler gave is not relevant, because he's using a different sense than the question asked about.

Comment: @Barmar - OK. The poetic example (a poem of renown) may have been somewhat elliptical as an answer, but it was not, and is not, irrelevant to the OP's question. Moreover, in my comment to OP I didn't equate '*out of*' with '*From among*', you were right, that wouldn't have served, so instead I typed "*out of=from*" Mr. Lawler's comment was relevant and precisely on point. *Mr. Humbulani wanted to use 'out of' to replace 'from among' in the sense of *separation from an original status*. e.g.*Out of the night" is = with "*Out of ten skiers, one."  one...*"

Comment: @Barmar - sometimes the Answer challenges, doesn't do all the work. The Answer invites further reflection in order to fully complete the process of learning. This *could be* the case here. Peace.

Comment: but, Humbulani, if my criticisms were misplaced or excessive, I apologize and beg your forgiveness. For, who am I? *Out of dust come I. To dust I return*. :-)

Answer (score 1):

"Of" on its own is a more economical usage.  When used at the beginning of a phrase or sentence, "out of"/"of" tends to suggest that there is a large number of whatever is being described, and as such, the word "all" is usually added.  This also elevates the importance of the individual in the following clause.

For example: 
"Of all the courtiers, James Smigglebottom was the King's favourite"
"Out of all the cows, Bessie had the most splendid udders"

"Out of" is most commonly used at the beginning of a sentence preceding a noun, such as "out of spite, Nessie hid her udders from the farmer's view" or "out of reluctance to interfere with court politics, James Smigglebottom bought a one-way ticket to Bognor Regis, lived out his days there as a hermit, and was neither seen by the King, nor by anybody else, until those calamitous events of 1734".

Comment: "two out of three ain't bad"?

Answer (score 1):

**Out Of** *vs* **From Among**

[**merriam-webster**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of)

> **Out of**: (*preposition*) **4**.—used as a *function* word ***to indicate choice or selection from a group***--*one out of four survived*.
>
> **From**: (*preposition*)—used to indicate the starting point of a physical movement or action—used to indicate the place that something ***comes out of***. **2**.—used as a *function* word to indicate ***physical separation or an act or condition of removal***, abstention, exclusion, release, subtraction, or differentiation.

[**Cambridge Dictionaries**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/out-of)

> **Out of**: (*preposition*) (***From among***) ***from among a group or a particular number***: The poll showed that ***six out of ten people*** approved of the job the president is doing.
> ***selected out of***, ***selected from among***.

An Ngram query of **selected out of, selected from among** indicated that both are established and permissible uses of the English language--***in the sense that the OP requires***--it also indicates that **from among** is currently the more popular choice.

**selected out of, selected from among** [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=selected+out+of%2Cselected+from+among&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cselected%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cselected%20from%20among%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: +1 @MrHen - do I even need the "@" to ping you? Thank you. Now, how do we rid ourselves of the duplicate - is it as simple as a delete?

Comment: You should be able to delete it, yes.